# how to change the label from leaflet-control-layers-toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, leaflet

I am using mapbox and leaflet on my website, and I need to change label "Satellite"  from leaflet-control-layers-toggle to "SAT".

How can I change it using leaflet?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Please have you checked Leaflet API for [Layers Control](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers)?

```js
var baseLayers = {
  "Mapbox": mapbox,
  "OpenStreetMap": osm
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map);
```

with `"Mapbox"` and `"OpenStreetMap"` being the names that will be displayed in the Layers Control.